# Where do questions about specific software belong?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1050427/437712) asks about Vim on Ask Ubuntu.  To me, this seems like it would be a better fit on Super User.

Are there any clear rules about where questions about specific software belongs?

Comment: There is also a [vi.se] that might accept the question. Look at their guidelines first though because I am not a member of their community.

Comment: The question's upvoted and answered. Why shouldn't it be where it is? The site seems happy to accept it. Sites are allowed to have overlapping scope and the users who ask the question get to choose which site they ask on. If it's off topic there, it's one thing... that's when you go looking for an alternate, but if it's on topic, it stays. :)

Comment: I've had this kind of problem myself. What if I wanted to ask a question about Microsoft Excel and it has an answer? There's no site for it here, yet it is clearly a mainstream and professional topic with practical utility. Should there not simply be a general software help site?

Comment: @JohnJoe Have you looked at [su]? I think they have lots of questions about Excel there.

Comment: I will take a look but I don't understand how the term "super user" is well fitted for people seeking help on specific software, I never would have guessed that. I would use "Software Help" if I want help with software. And if someone isn't an expert at certain software, are they really a super user then? I also don't need the "best" performance, as implied by "power user."

Comment: @Catija, if they are happy, I have no issue with it.  I am just wondering if there are rules about this thing other than "if X rejects it, try somewhere else".

Comment: @jkd, I think that that supports my point, does it not?  If there is a Vi and Vim SE, should all Vi/m questions not be directed to it?  Else, what is the point of that SE?

Comment: Downvoters: any comments?